# Email spoofing issue from salesforce - emails not getting through to recipients

Tags: email, administration, security, configuration

If I send emails from an email-enabled object within Salesforce, e.g., case, the emails do not always get delivered to recipients. I have discovered that one or two of the recipients have these emails quarantined on account of "anti-spoofing" rules set on the email server. 
Is there a setting in my salesforce org that I should have enabled/disabled in order to stop this issue occurring?
In particular, I do not have Email Security Compliance enabled.

Comment: Here is some reference material about IP addresses that emails are sent from that may help you https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?language=en_US&id=000003652.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable "Enable Sender ID compliance" under Deliverability, the downside is that all the emails will show as coming from no-reply@salesforce.com.

Another option would be to implement the Email Relay feature.

You can read more about this here :

http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=emailadmin_deliverability.htm